# gdal.RasterizeLayer can not burn any values or use attribute from shapefile in python

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to rasterize a shapefile but the raster produced by the code it has only 0 as a value. The extends and projection is correct but I am not able to set any value in the raster. I need to use the "lucode" from the shapefile. This is an integer field in the shp. I have aso tried to burn a single value to the raster with no luck.

below please find the code I am working on:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
# Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster
pixel_size = 5000
NoData_value = -9999

# Filename of input OGR file
vector_fn = r'D:\Africa\01_carbon\DRC\shp\LULC_join.shp'

# Filename of the raster Tiff that will be created
raster_fn =  r'D:\Africa\01_carbon\DRC\shp\test.tif'

# Open the data source and read in the extent
source_ds = ogr.Open(vector_fn)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()
source_srs = source_layer.GetSpatialRef()

# Create the destination data source
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)

target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_fn, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_max, 0, -pixel_size))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

target_ds.SetProjection(source_srs.ExportToWkt())

#print(target_ds, [1], source_layer.name)

# Rasterize
#gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, 
#                    [1], source_layer, 
#                    burn_values=[3]) # try to burn a contant value (3)

# Rasterize
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, 
                    [1], source_layer, 
                    options = ["ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE", "ATTRIBUTE=lucode"]) #using an attribute from the shapefile
```

Comment: Is the output layer the correct size and resolution,  and CRS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied your code and made a grid of rectangles. It also didn't work.

After the rasterize statement, add:

```
target_ds.FlushCache()
del target_ds
```

It works!